# Из текстового файла в очередь Qu1 C++

Tags: c++11

Дан текстовый файл с изображением целых чисел, которые необходимо переписать в очередь Qu1. Удалить из очереди все двузначные числа и записать оставшиеся в файл.

Comment: Зачем удалять из очереди то, что можно в неё не добавлять? И вообще, зачем очередь?

Comment: @test123 гораздо интереснее текстовый файл с картинкой. С псевдографикой - ладно. С изображением... нет.

Comment: можно цыфры звездочками набивать. Очень хорошая задача получается (особенно, если шрифт не стандартизировать).